# Is System.Object.MemberwiseClone thread-safe in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class derived from `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. Its instance is shared in application between different threads. I need to serialize my custom list and because of multi-thread sharing, I'm getting sometimes `System.InvalidOperationException` exception with message

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

For serialization, I use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` and to solve the problem  I use `MemberwiseClone` method to create a shallow copy of the list and then do serialization. My custom list contains immutable objects, so shallow copy is enough.

My question is if two threads will call `MemberwiseClone` simultaneously will it be thread-safe? 
I didn't find anything about this in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) and MemberwiseClone 
[implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,123) is unfortunately external. I've found a [post](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1547922/dotnet/langages/csharp/memberwiseclone-thread-safe/) about this in French and after translation, it is still unclear.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a thread-safe collection like [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: I would be more worried about whether or not the original object is being modified while MemberWiseClone is executing.  MemberWiseClone itself should be threadsafe; it's only reading your original object, not writing it.  Calling MemberWiseClone simultaneously from two different threads on the same object should simply produce two shallow clones, but if the underlying object is being modified from a third thread, I don't think there's any guarantee that your two clones will be identical.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto a good question. But it is old legacy code, to change this requires big refactoring.

Comment: `MemberwiseClone` is just a wrapper around `memmove`/`memcpy`, with the source and destination protected from GC ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp#L237)). This is thread-safe for concurrent reads, but there is no guarantee you'll get a consistent view of the object if it's concurrently modified. The latter is easy to establish empirically with a small program.